# Mobile margins and centering with using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have been able to center elements with margins equal on both sides in mobile without using bootstrap.

My landing page, however, I have used boostrap columns and centered them. I run into problems with mobile portrait display. Landscape display looks fine, everything is centered.

What I have tried:
-setting width to word container and box to 280px and shrinking my navigation menu accordingly.That didn't work.

I am thinking it might be that I have a width for col-centered of 500px which might be what is wrong.

My site can be viewed @ http://lewisdesigns.github.io

Comment: Please add the relevant code here instead of a link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

> the link for your project "www.lewisdesigns.github.io" not working. ok
>   not an issue but i will like to tell you to remove margin-left and
>   margin-right and add

```
"margin:0px auto;"
```

> to css selector of each element (e.g. class/id); besides you can also
>   try for

```
"float:none; text-align:center;"
```

> in this case.